# How can I view the protocol used in Chrome developer tools network tab?

Tags: google-chrome, url-scheme, web-inspector

The network tab on Chrome developer toolbar is great, but I'd like to see what protocol was used to transfer the resource (HTTP or HTTPS). Anyone knows how I can do this, or if there's an extension to allow me to do something similar.

Answer (score 130, accepted):

Well, this is 2016 and now you can have a column for protocols in your chrome devtools. All you have to do is:

1) open your **networks tab** in devtools and right click on any of column headers to open the "select columns" popup

2) select **protocol** (or any other desired column) for it to appear in the panel

[image]

And that's it!

[image]

Comment: It's 2019 now, everything is https hopefully :D

Comment: OK, apparently you have to specifically right-click the "Waterfall" column header to change visible columns now...

Comment: Ha! The right click had me stumped

Comment: @JohnHunt Hello from 2024! I came here because the program I'm writing fails to download a file, and now I know why: it's being served over HTTP 0.9, which my library doesn't support, as it dates back to 1991. Please give my regards to this futuristic thing that you called "HTTPS".

Answer (score 7):

Click on the resource in the "Name" column (on the very left), then select the "Headers" tab. The first line will look like this:

> Request URL: [How can I view the protocol used in chrome developer tools network tab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12213421/how-can-i-view-the-protocol-used-in-chrome-developer-tools-network-tab)

The request url contains the protocol.

Comment: Shame you can't get it in a new column :/

Comment: A pitty you can't filter by protocol in the network tab :/

Comment: yay recursive answer

Comment: now you can. i have shown it in my answer below (the question was marked "answered", but still)

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12213421/how-can-i-view-the-protocol-used-in-chrome-developer-tools-network-tab/38084721#38084721

Answer (score 1):

You could use the JavaScript console by entering:

```
location.protocol
```

This will return you a string of the used network protocol, such as:

- "https:"

or

- "http:"

Comment: How to retrieve its version using JavaScript?

Comment: That's actually the scheme and not the protocol.