# net::ERR_SPDY_PROTOCOL_ERROR in chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I'm using JS-autocomplete which is working fine in the local environment, but in Live environment, initially autocomplete works properly, but after 3-4 attempts I'm getting `net::ERR_SPDY_PROTOCOL_ERROR` in the console (only in one page).
This is not the case for all pages, other pages have the same autocomplete which is working properly, I have tried in incognito mode and some other browsers, but getting the same error

I have tried following methods

Cleared temp files, cookies, and caches

Flushing SPDY Sockets using `chrome://net-internals/#sockets`

Updated browser

Flushing DNS and Renewing IP

but these attempts did not solve my problem

Note: I have not installed any Antivirus

Snapshot of Network panel

[image]

Comment: Try using https for you site.

Comment: @ Rohit Garg it's already using https, but I tried with HTTP and it's properly working

Comment: Can you provide snapshot of your network panel with 'Protocol' header in view.

Comment: This snapshot is having insufficient data, try taking snapshot with 'Protocol' header(ref - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12213421/how-can-i-view-the-protocol-used-in-chrome-developer-tools-network-tab)

Comment: @RohitGarg New snapshot is added with protocol header

Comment: @ANEES did you find a solution ? I have the same issue.

Comment: @CharlieWebNancy Problem is in the network...
as I have tried this on another network and it worked properly,
Contact your network Provider

Answer (score 0):

Try following two things :-

1. Use http2 protocol for loading your resources as well and for the auto-complete API.
2. Use unique identifier for your auto-complete API(like &t=(new Date()).getTime())